# Kendo MVC Razor Grid How to pass a single model rather collection from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

For a normal scenario, Kendo MVC Razor or any other grid supposedly be bound to a collection where controller passes the DataSourceRequest to the DataSourceResult of the collection and return Json result as follow

```
    public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string taskKey)
    {
        var query = eSerivce.GetData(taskKey);
        var result = query.modelCollection.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Above code work fine for any kind of collection and grid will render the data fine.

In my scenario, I have a single model returned rather a collection by the service layer and as there is no ToDataSourceResult available on single entity so I can't pass the DataSourceRequest to it and without DataSourceRequest it is not rendering any information.

e.g.

```
    public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string taskKey)
    {
        var query = eSerivce.GetData(taskKey);
        var result = query.   // no ToDataSourceResult available here because of single model
        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In above snippet as there is no ToDataSourceResult available, when I return query, Grid dont render any data. I know I can convert my single model entity to a collection to apply the necessory operation but I am just wondering if there is any other way of work around to this situation. Main reason of returning only one record is to display the excessive information of the parent grid in a custom templated row on a row expand.

Comment: `"I know I can convert my single model entity to a collection"` - That's how I'd do it.  If the framework components are expecting a collection (as a grid would), then pass it a collection.  A collection populated by one element is still a collection.  And I imagine considerably easier than to try to modify the components to bind to a non-collection object.

Comment: If you are displaying extra information about a parent record in this way then why are you using a grid in the child template? Couldn't you use a control that is better suited for a non-collection model?

Comment: @RossBush grid is used to send a on demand ajax call on row expand. What other control do you suggest for this purpose? Just to let you know I am in a template within a template so just firing up a jQuery ajax call is not an option as anything i write will be with in the @<text> </text> tags of the template.

Comment: @LearningCurve That makes more sense. You don't want to clutter up the @<text><text>.I though that maybe you were using client template's or partials for this, in which case it would be easy to display the info.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo DataSource (not only grid) expect array, return model in different way:

if simple list:

```
return Json(new[] { query }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

or if `type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"`

```
return Json(new[] { query }.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```